# Text overlapping text

Tags: html, css, text, overlap

This is my issue
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL4zX.jpg

If i wrap this part of the html code in comment < !-- and --> marks, it will erase this text, but the overlap will spread to the next part like a virus. if i delete the comment tags, the overlap will happen twice. if i comment out both over laps, it will spread out two more overlaps. delete the comment, and now i have 4 overlaps, oh joy.
Can any1 help? i don't want an ellipsis.

I didn't find any syntax errors in my html or css code.
this is perfectly what i want
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGPRE.jpg
perfectly fine

**Update:**

This is the relevant page where I get the error:
http://chucpina.net63.net/errors.html

Comment: So you're expect us to guess what's wrong or are you want to add some HTML in the question?

Comment: As @AlonEitan mentioned, please could you post the problematic code?

Comment: even if the text pops out of the div window, it just pops out and doesnt overlap the next div box. i just need to adjust the boxes so no text pops out. how do i stop it from overlapping?

Comment: thats the thing, i cant find my mistake

Comment: lemme upload the html code to a webpage

Comment: Create  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and you'll probably get the help you need

Comment: http://chucpina.net63.net/errors.html

Comment: type "view-source:" before the url to view the source code

Comment: here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=O326mCFtHj

Answer (score 0):

You have the following style:

```
#pro1 {
    border-radius: 15px 50px;
    background: #FBD8BC;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 120px;
}
```

Note that the height is 120px, so change it to:

```
#pro1 {
    border-radius: 15px 50px;
    background: #FBD8BC;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

And it should work. Note that you're using static height in the `#ing2` style as well.

Comment: thanks so much, i can finally take a nap :D ive been up for like 7 hrs trying to find a fix